# Updating the timestamp of a row when copied from another table

Tags: mysql, timestamp, copy

I've been working at this for a while now and I haven't been able to come up with a solution, so i'm not sure if this may even be possible but any help is greatly appreciated.

I have two tables with a very basic structure as follows:

> CREATE TABLE test ( time timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL );
>
> CREATE TABLE test_copy_to ( time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );

I then create an entry in the "test" table that has a NULL value i.e. no given time:

> INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL);

I then would like to copy the NULL value from the "test" table to the "test_copy_to" table as follows:

> INSERT INTO test_copy_to SELECT * FROM test;

The first problem is that the "test_copy_to" won't accept NULL values which is what is initialized in the first table. However what I would like to achieve is being able to copy the value from "test" (while having the null value) to "test_copy_to" such that the time-stamp is updated to the time at which it was copied from one table to the other. I've tried using UPDATE on the variable time however that does not seem to work. Is there anyway I can create the table such that it behaves in this manner?

Answer (score 2):

Instead use `COALESCE()` function like below to provide some default values where the value is `null`

```
INSERT INTO test_copy_to 
SELECT coalesce(`time`, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) FROM test;
```